# How to get more CPU power on Openshift?

Tags: openshift

Using openshift online, is there a way to get more CPU performance from a gear? Is CPU performance related to gear size? Why there is no mention of GHz/no of cores for a gear? If single thread performance of a single small gear is not enough for me, do I have any options or Openshift is not for me?

Answer (score 0):

To get more CPU performance from a gear you need to use a larger gear size. There is an algorithm that OpenShift uses to share CPU between gears based on gear size.  It's not a Virtual Machine, it's an SELinux container.

Comment: Ok, but what is the relation between gear size and CPU performance? Medium gear = 2x speed of small gear? 4x maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The only info on gears that I can find is the memory.  Small gears have 512MB of RAM, Medium have 1GB, and large have 2GB.